# Can I set one profile for every server I connect with SSH?

Tags: ssh, inputrc

I need to create new VMs in the cloud very often for my job.
Every time I connect a new remote server with `ssh`, I need to set some configs like `completion-ignore-case on` in my `~/.inputrc` manually.

Is there anyway to set up these kind of config once and run everywhere?

Comment: Yes, by using an automated deployment solution.

Comment: Setting up that file should (or at least could) be part of deploying the VM.

Comment: Sounds like I should do this before starting up a VM. But if I got several existed VMs , can I still set a file once for all of them?

Answer (score 0):

> Every time I connect a new remote server with ssh, I need to set some configs like completion-ignore-case on in my ~/.inputrc manually.

On the local or remote machine ?

For local machine, see the following option in `.ssh/config`: (extracted from `man 5 ssh_config`):

```
     LocalCommand
             Specifies a command to execute on the local machine
             after successfully connecting to the server.  The
             command string extends to the end of the line, and is
             executed with the user's shell.  Arguments to
             LocalCommand accept the tokens described in the
             TOKENS section.

             The command is run synchronously and does not have
             access to the session of the ssh(1) that spawned it.
             It should not be used for interactive commands.

             This directive is ignored unless PermitLocalCommand
             has been enabled.
```

For a remote command execution, you may use the `SendEnv` option to set the `INPUTRC` variable to your specially (pre-)crafter inputrc file (see `man 1 bash` and search for INPUTRC)

Comment: Even if you set `INPUTRC`, you'd still need to pre-craft that file, and then you might as well use `~/.inputrc`. I think OP wants to avoid that step.

Comment: I do not have solution to avoid this step ...